# updateStateByKey, noClassDefFoundError

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt, spark-streaming, sbt-assembly

I have problem with using updateStateByKey() function. I have following, simple code (written base on book: *"Learning Spark - Lighting Fast Data Analysis"*):

```
object hello {
  def updateStateFunction(newValues: Seq[Int], runningCount: Option[Int]): Option[Int] = {
    Some(runningCount.getOrElse(0) + newValues.size)
  }


  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[5]").setAppName("AndrzejApp")
    val ssc = new StreamingContext(conf, Seconds(4))
    ssc.checkpoint("/")

    val lines7 = ssc.socketTextStream("localhost", 9997)
    val keyValueLine7 = lines7.map(line => (line.split(" ")(0), line.split(" ")(1).toInt))


    val statefullStream = keyValueLine7.updateStateByKey(updateStateFunction _)
    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
  }

}
```

My build.sbt is:

```
name := "stream-correlator-spark"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.4"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.3.1" % "provided",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "1.3.1" % "provided"
)
```

When I build it with `sbt assembly` command everything goes fine. When I run this on spark cluster in local mode I got error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/streaming/dstream/DStream$
at hello$.main(helo.scala:25)
...

line 25 is:

```
val statefullStream = keyValueLine7.updateStateByKey(updateStateFunction _)
```

I feel this might be some compatibility version problem but I don't know what might be the reason and how to resolve this.

I would be really grateful for help!

Comment: I have checked jar file that is created with `sbt assembly` and it doesn't contain any jars (or classes) related to spark or spark streaming. Shouldn't `sbt assembly` contain all sources needed to run on any JVM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are writing `"provided"` in the SBT this means exactly that your library is provided by the environment and need no to be included in the package.
Try to remove `"provided"` mark from `"spark-streaming"` library.

Answer (score 0):

You can add "provided" back when you need to submit your app to a spark cluster to run. The benefit of having "provided" is that the result fat jar will not include classes from the provided dependencies, which will yield a much smaller fat jar, comparing to not having "provided". In my case, the result jar will be around 90M without "provided" and then shrink to 30+M with "provided".